# How to use interface in class methode

Tags: php

I am struggling to understand what arguments to use for a particular methode from a class in PHP.

```php
$client = new Client();
$client->execute();
```

The `execute()` methode requires an argument. Looking at the `execute()` methode in the `Client` class it seems linked (linked is probably not the right word here) to the `RequestInterface` interface. Which contains two methodes: `getMethod()` and `getPath()`. How do I use the `execute()` methode?

```php
    class Client
    { 
            public function execute(RequestInterface $request)
            {
                 //do stuff
            }
    }
```

```
interface RequestInterface
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMethod();

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath();
}
```

Comment: The `Client::execute()` method needs an object of type `RequestInterface`. You'd need to _implement_ the `RequestInterface` to create such an object and _inject_ it into the  `Client::execute()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment, that would look something like this. Class `MyRequest` implements interface `RequestInterface`. You can then inject method `Client::execute()` with a `RequestInterface` type object (`$request`).

```
<?php
Class MyRequest implements RequestInterface
{
    public function getMethod()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getMethod() method.
    }

    public function getPath()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getPath() method.
    }
}

class Client
{
    public function execute(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

interface RequestInterface
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMethod();

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath();
}

$request = new MyRequest();
$client = (new Client)->execute($request);

var_dump($client); //0
```

see it [in action](https://3v4l.org/K8O56)

Suggested reading https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php